# what is the function of $value & 15

Tags: arrays, perl

I have been going over a perl book i have recently purchased, and while reading I noticed a block of code that confused me..

```
use integer;
$value = 257;

while($value){
   unshift @digits, (0..9,a..f)[$value & 15];
   $value /= 16;
}
print digits;
```

the book mentions the purpose was to reverse the order of digits. however, new to perl I am having trouble figuring out what [$value & 15] is doing.

Comment: When I don't know what something means in Perl, `perldoc` is the first place I look. Unfortunately, if you're a beginner, you might not know exactly *where* in `perldoc` to look, so it can take some digging around. In this case, we have a variable followed by our "mystery symbol" followed by a constant. This looks like an operator, kind of like the `+` in `$foo + 15`. Operators are documented in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-And); the nice thing about `perldoc` is you can search for symbols like `&` that you can't easily google. The explanation of *(continued)*

Comment: *(continued)* `&` in `perldoc` isn't very helpful if you don't know about bitwise operations, but it does give us the name of the operator ("bitwise AND"), which we can now google for a better explanation. Other common places to look are `perldoc perlvar` for documentation on special variables like `$/`, `perldoc perlsyn` for documentation on Perl syntax, and `perldoc -f function` for documentation on functions (e.g. `perldoc -f sort`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [bitwise and](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node36.html) operation.

What it's doing is performing a bitwise and using the value of 15 and whatever value is contained in `$value`.

The resulting value is the decimal value that corresponds to the result of a bitwise and with the lower 4 bits of the value.

Ex:

```
$value = 21
   which has a binary representation of: 0b10101
```

Performing a `bitwise and` with 15 means that any bits in `$value` will be zeroed if they are either outside the lower 4 bit range, or contain no 1's in the lower 4 bits.

The result is:

```
0b10101
&
0b 1111
-------
0b00101 = 5
```

Looking up the truth tables for performing bitwise operations will help with stuff like this in the future, but when performing an AND with any value, the result is *only* true, when both bits are 1, 0 otherwise.

```
V1 | V2 | V1 & V2
-----------------
 0 | 0  |    0
 0 | 1  |    0
 1 | 0  |    0
 1 | 1  |    1
```

Comment: and the `(...)[...]` is a list slice that uses what's in the square brackets as indexes for elements of the list to return